# "Error: Address aleready in use" during docker build command

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build an image from a Dockerfile in order to launch multiple containers from it. In the Dockerfile I copy my */etc/apt/source/sources.list* and then execute several command (apt update, and apt install) using the RUN keyword.

When I execute the docker build command, the execution starts correctly and I see intermediary containers being created and deleted. But at some point I get an error telling me "Address already in use".

When I inspect the last intermediary container created, in the state section I get:

> Status: created
>   ...
>   Pid : 0
>   ExitCode: 128
>   Error: Adress already in use

**EDIT:**

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM i386/debian AS node

COPY sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN apt-get install -y vim gdb valdgrind
RUN apt-get-install -y python

...
```

The last output I get from the build command is:

```
Step 4/37 : RUN apt-get update
 ----> Running in ce7722ffeeb6
Address already in use
```

**END EDIT**

I don't understand what this error is about. Does anybody have an idea?

I'm running on Debian 9 with Docker 17.12.0.

Comment: Please provide your Dockerfile and/or the last line of the `docker build` output, which should container the last executed Dockerfile statement, which causes the error

Comment: I posted the Dockerfile and output

Comment: Looks kind of odd, what is the content of your `sources.list`? Does the problem persist if you remove the `COPY sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list` line? Does your problem persist if you switch from `FROM i386/debian` to another base image, say `FROM ubuntu`?

Answer (score 0):

This means that one of the ports that you affected to one of your containers is currently already used by another container or by another application on your machine.

A good example is if you are running your app both in a container with a port explicitely exposed by docker, and at the same time running it from your IDE.

If this does not make the problem for you can you paste us your dockerfile ?

Comment: Ok, that could be it. But how I am supposed to avoid using the same ports? I mean, docker is creating, overlaying and deleting those temporary containers by itself to create the image I ask for right? Once I get my image and create my own containers based on it, I know how to control their deployment but I never ask for those temporary containers so I don't see how I can control the ports they use?

Comment: In docker you always have to explicity Expose the ports you want to be able to reach from outside the container, in your case I expect it is the port 80 since you have a server, but I can't say because I don't see your EXPOSE line in the dockerfile you provided (can you add it ? ). Then when you start your container you must be using -p to say how the mapping should go , can you show us your command to start the container ?